# What happens to the missing coins in this transaction? Copy paste this code into remix to reproduce my original bug. Thank you

Tags: solidity, transactions, ether, tokens, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TheCaseOfTHeMissingCoins{

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    address public owner;

    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);


    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) public {
       initialSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals); 
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;               
        name = tokenName;                                 
        symbol = tokenSymbol;    
        owner = msg.sender;

    }

        //Using a different account than the one used to initialize the contract
    //please call this function with the value of 5.208333333333330000(ether) in remix
    //then check the account balance
    function TESTbuyCoins() public payable{
        uint amount = TESTcalculateAmountOfCoins(msg.value);
        _transfer(owner, msg.sender, amount);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    //we should be getting 250000000000000000000 but instead when this 
    //runs we get 249999999999999840000.
    //What happens to the missing coins?

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }


    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function TESTcalculateAmountOfCoins(uint coinsWanted) public returns(uint totalCoins){
            totalCoins = coinsWanted * 48;
        return(totalCoins);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Solved!!! It turns out it since I was doing the calculations in Google Sheets the numbers were getting rounded. Case Closed.